# Google Chrome - how to communicate through serial port on client side using javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Only with Google Chrome/Canary/Chromium, how to communicate through serial port on client side hardware using Javascript. Is there any open-source example/framework/sample on this, how it can be done for Google Chrome/Canary/Chromium only?

Tried this but its for Beagle board only: https://github.com/beagleterm/beagle-term
i just need the very basic read/write options.

Comment: Use [`chrome.serial`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial) for Chrome Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [chrome.serial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial) API provides access to client serial ports from a Chrome App. The beagle-term app looks like a good starting point for writing a generic serial terminal app and provides an example for reading and writing data to the serial port for whatever application you are trying to write.

Comment: Can you share an example for quick start please?

Comment: beagle-term is a good example. Here are some other sample serial apps:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/serial